# website images not showing on mobile

Tags: html, css, image

I am completely new to web programming, and am having difficulty trying to figure out why some images don't show up on mobile devices. Current website works fine on PC browsers, but on mobile it sometimes works sometimes doesn't. The images sometimes show up fine on Android devices and rarely on an iPad but I haven't seen them work on an iPhone yet. Sometimes I see one or two images displayed for a second then they are gone.

I have scraped basic template from internet and changed code here and there, but default images that came with template works just fine, but my own images don't. For example images in [About page](http://www.kooyigrill.com/about.html) show up all the time but images in [Menu page](http://www.kooyigrill.com/menu.html) don't.

For the code-wise, there is nothing special, I just used the same format for all of them.

```
<div class="portfolio-box wow fadeInUp">  
    <div class="portfolio-box-container">  
        <img src="assets/img/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" data-at2x="assets/img/gallery/1.jpg">  
    </div>  
</div>
```

I suspected this be a problem with image size so tried making image size smaller to match the size of default images, but it still doesn't seem to work. What could be a possible problem here?

I have verified multiple times all image routes, extension names and case sensitivity.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. We normally expect to see some code. PS Neither of your URLS work

Comment: I get four images on the menu, working for me in mobile too.

Comment: may I ask which phone you are using? It sometimes seems to work, but I just want to be sure it works all the time

Comment: may be its create problem due to animate js in mobile device..

Comment: @tree1814 I'm using a BQ Aquaris E4.5, the browser I'm using is Lightning Browser +, Chrome is working too. Make sure you are not using "desktop mode" load in your mobile web-browser.

Comment: Now suddenly it's disappearing last image on the `../menu.html` in my desktop browser, now I see your problem. Just checked the code in the debugger, and the image is there, it's just hidden. Must be something related with Javascript.

Comment: Well I think I traced the root of the problem, not sure how to fix it yet. First check this: https://u.pomf.is/siwmdu.png these two images are not animated yet, so they are still hidden.